# Deleting local profile after user logs off?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, roaming-profile

I am currently using roaming profiles and wante to configure all clients connected to the domain to delete the local profile once the user logs off.

Could this be done via a Group Policy?  Script?

Comment: Is this server running on a VMware host? If so, do you have VMware tools installed? If so, do you have the Shared Folders component of VMware Tools installed? If so, uninstall that component. There's a known issue with cached copies of roaming profiles not being deleted if the Shared Folders component of VMware Tools is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the following Group Policy:

> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> User Profiles
>
> Delete cached copies of roaming profiles

Comment: I've tried this yesterday, however the copy is still on the local machine.  Would I need any other configuration done as well as the GP?

Comment: @joesafe: gpupdate /force ?

Comment: What OS are the clients? And is the full profile definitely still there? Log on to a box and compare your own, currently logged on profile folders with that of the 'should be deleted' ones. It may be that certain folders can't be deleted, but the bulk is going.

Comment: In addition to what @BartSilverstrim says, you should also check the event viewer.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to do gpupdate /force.  Thanks, I will give this another shot and hopefully it will work this time.

Also, the clients are mostly Windows 7 with a couple of XP's around.

Comment: I've done all this, however it still leaves a folder (named: the users username).  This folder is empty.  Is this correct?

Comment: @JoeSafe Yeah, I see that a lot - I think it's to do with files being locked and the like. It's not caused any issues in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to configuring profile deletion via Group Policy you might want to check out my free tool Delprof2 which deletes inactive profiles on all versions of Windows both locally and remotely.

You can find more information about Delprof2 here:

http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/